# How to disable or program dark/night mode in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-dark-theme

I want to know if it is possible to disable night/dark mode into android studio´s apps because, in my case, it breaks my app´s aesthetic.

I´ve tried using this code line into all my activities but it didn´t work:

```
setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

If there aren´t any way to disable night/dark mode, can you tell me what do i have to do in order to make my app respond properly to color changes due to night/dark mode? (This includes background colors, drawable´s shapes colors and every color that gets modified by this mode)

(I accept documentation or any kind of information that can helps me solving this BIG problem)

**My styles.xml:**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:padding">7dp</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Dark mode does not affect your app unless you do something in the app that enables it. For example, you might have chosen a `DayNight` theme. Find out what in your app has enabled dark mode support, then change it.

Comment: Hello @CommonsWare and thanks so much for answering. Where do you recommend me to look for? Ive checked my styles  and i cant figure out whats the problem. I´ve updated my question showing my styles.xml

Comment: OK, nothing in there suggests that you would be adapting to dark mode automatically. But, I see where [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme) suggest that `android:forceDarkAllowed="true"` is being set automatically by some system themes (which IMHO is seriously stupid). Try adding `<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>` to your `AppTheme` and see if that helps.

Comment: Broooo, thanks you so much. @CommonsWare that code worked

Comment: Remember that `Dark Mode` is not `Night Mode`. They are completely different. DM was introduce in Android 10 that enforce built-in black and white color while NM was on earlier version that uses either default/defined style depending on your implementation. If you want your app to use your define light/night style and not relying on built-in dark style, you may want to `forceDarkAllowed` to false in themes.xml or style.xml as DM may conflict.

Answer (score 3):

Finally solved the problem disabling dark/night mode. We have to add the following code into our AppThemes:

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
```